# I know how to toggle show/hide a div onclick, but how to do that for onpress?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, onpress

I have a div I'm hiding behind a button I want to toggle "onpress". I want that div to only be visible when someone presses down on the button layered above it.

I'm only aware of how to use `onclick` for toggling visibility. See the snippet.

I simply want a press function that toggles the show/hide of the button above the hidden div.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("button1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
button {
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    }

#button1 {
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 10vw;
    z-index: 1000;    
}

#hiddendiv1 {
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 10vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
  justify-content: center; 
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<div id=button1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">I want to toggle this button div off during "onpress"</button>
</div>

<div id=hiddendiv1>
I want to see this div ONLY when the button is being "pressed" down. 
</div>
```

Comment: you should do the onkeydown and onkeyup events to toggle a variable that determines the hidden/shown state of the div.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `mousedown` event – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  console.log('tada');
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Press me, but never let go. ;)</button>
```

Cheers!

Comment: for some reason switching between display="none" and "block" doesn't work for hiding/showing the div.
`function mouseDown() {
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none";`
}

Comment: `.style.visibility = "hidden";` doesn't work for me either for `mouseUp` when I want to return the div to visible